# Asus X550LA with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, 13.10, asus, function-keys

I am using [this Asus notebook](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X550LA/) with Ubuntu 13.10. All my function keys (Wifi, Bluetooth, Sound, etc.) are not working! Wifi gets started on boot up, but can not connect to most of the networks.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

See

https://askubuntu.com/questions/442395/kubuntu-on-a-asus-x551c-fn-keys-not-working

No one helped me... but at least kubuntu is useable now.